# End CASE statement after the condition is fulfilled

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Let's say there are some phone numbers connected to people and those phone numbers have indexes.

1. I need to pick a number with an index 16389 first.
2. In case if previous doesn't exist, or is empty, I need to pick a number with an index 16385.
3. In case if previous also doesn't exist, I need to pick a number connected to a person's company (here index isn't important).

The restriction is, only one of this numbers should be displayed- so, if there's a number with 16389 index, only it should be displayed, even if there is a number with 16385 index or a company number. The CASE statement doesn't work (or possibly I can't construct it to work as desired).

Here's the example (not working) of what I was thinking about:

```
(CASE 
    WHEN pho.ptype_idx = 16389 THEN pho.phone END
    ELSE WHEN pho.ptype_idx = 16385 THEN pho.phone END
    ELSE pho1.phone (this is the company phone number)
 END) as 'column1'
```

The question is, how can I force CASE to end after the condition is true? Because now it returns duplicate rows, only with phone number changed. Or maybe another approach would be better? I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Can you elaborate on not working? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: Only one END needed, the last one. And no ELSE before WHEN.

Answer (score 2):

A `case` expression does not generate additional rows.  That part of your question does not really make sense.

Your `case` is not syntactically correct.  The correct formulation would be:

```
(CASE WHEN pho.ptype_idx = 16389 THEN pho.phone
      WHEN pho.ptype_idx = 16385 THEN pho.phone
      ELSE pho1.phone (this is the company phone number)
 END) as column1
```

At the very least, this is syntactically correct, so it should at least work.  It might also fix your problem.

This can be more simply written as:

```
(CASE WHEN pho.ptype_idx IN (16389, 16385) THEN pho.phone
      ELSE pho1.phone (this is the company phone number)
 END) as column1
```

Comment: Of course it works, and I've done it like this, but the problem is that it returns three rows for one person in case if there are phone numbers with indexes 16389 ,16385, and the company's phone number- and I need to stop at only one row-in order that I've specified in the question. Is there any way to end the CASE after one condition is met, and not check the rest?

Comment: @Pocia . . . I would suggest that you ask *another* question.  Provide sample data, desired results.  If you include SQL, try to be sure it is syntactically correct.  This question is unclear and the syntactically incorrect SQL is a big distraction.  If you edit it now, it will not only invalidate this answer (attracting downvotes), but it will probably not get other answers.